# Is it a good way to use pgTAP framework to test postgresql functions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, postgresql, triggers

I am using posgresql database for my rails application. Now I need to test my trigger functions in the database. So, I saw some framework called pgTAP and is it a good way to test the trigger function in the database? I am not using perl. I am using Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 2):

Testing is a good thing and pgTAP can help you with the unit tests in your database.

- http://www.slideshare.net/justatheory/test-drivern-database-development
- http://www.slideshare.net/justatheory/unit-test-your-database
- http://www.slideshare.net/justatheory/pgtap-best-practices

Comment: And I imagine it wouldn't be too hard to integrate it into your regular `rake test` target (or whatever it's called in Railsland these days…).